# Edit record register with multiple subtitution

Tags: substitute

I recorded a register and it work normally.

I mistakenly overrode that register, fortunately I already saved the pattern.
It's as below:

```
V}y}pV}:s/_a\(\>\|_\)/_b\1/g^MpV}:s/_a\(\>\|_\)/_c\1/g^M
```

This means I copy a block (which have `_a` or `_a_`) and paste it to two others block, then change `_a` or `_a_` to `_b`, `_b_` and `_c`, `_c_`.

However, when I copy this line to my new register and execute, it don't understand that it need to replace ^M with Enter.
However, it stop at command line with exact whole register content.

I tried change ^M to `<C-M>` or `<CR>` or `<Enter>`, but they don't work also.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is one way. But to insert something into a register from a buffer (e.g. `"iy$`) as you were originally attempting to do...

Literal control-characters can be entered by prepending `^V` (CTRL-V). So before you yank your text into the register replace `^M` (caret plus letter "M") with what you get by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

This blog http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.com/2012/06/advanced-macros-in-vim-commentary.html help me to answer this question.

The content of register need to change to:

`V}y}pV}:s/_a\\(\\>\\|_\\)/_b\\1/g\<CR>pV}:s/_a\\(\\>\\|_\\)/_c\\1/g\<CR>`

Then use

`let @i = "V}y}pV}:s/_a\\(\\>\\|_\\)/_b\\1/g\<CR>pV}:s/_a\\(\\>\\|_\\)/_c\\1/g\<CR>"`

After that I can use my @i register.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"ip` to put the register into a buffer, edit it, then use `"iy$` or similar to put it back into the register.  This mostly preserves the meanings of special characters such as `^M`.